# Load data from other table using AJAX

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-backpack

When I try to fetch the data using the `AJAX` option I get an error saying that a column does not exist.

The main table that I am using is `users` and the other is `orders`. In the `User` model I have a relation set between both tables. In that case, the `orders` table has a `user_id` as FK.

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
}
```

And in the `UserCrudController` I set the `order` column to get the data using an accessor:

```
[
    'label' =>  'Orders',
    'name'  =>  'order_count',
],

// This method is in the `User` model
public function getOrderCountAttribute() {
    return count($this->orders);
}
```

So when I enable the `AJAX` I get the error that says that the column `order_count` does not exist in the `User` table. The relation and the accessor are not reached because I tried using `die()`.

Is there a way I can run the query using `AJAX`? I am using backpack 3 and laravel 5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [model_function](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-columns-types#section-model_function) column type. From what I can tell, for your case it would be:

```
[
   // run a function on the CRUD model and show its return value
   'name' => "order_count",
   'label' => "Orders", // Table column heading
   'type' => "model_function",
   'function_name' => 'getOrderCountAttribute', // the method in your Model
   // 'limit' => 100, // Limit the number of characters shown
]
```

Hope it helps!